# OnPress not working for Marker in react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-maps

I would like to perform some action when pressing one of the `Markers` on a map. What I have:

1) A `MapView`, like this:

```
<MapView
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    initialRegion={this.state.region}
    style={styles.map}>
    {this.displayRouteLocations(locations)}
</MapView>
```

2) My method `displayRouteLocations` does the following:

```
displayRouteLocations(locations) {
    return locations.map((location, i) => {
        return (
            <PointMarker
                key={i}
                coordinate={location}
                title={location.name}
                description={location.description}
                onPress={() => alert('test')}
            />
        );
    });
}
```

3) Finally, `PointMarker` is a separate component like this:

```
import {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

class PointMarker extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Marker
                {...this.props}
                pinColor={'#f6c23d'}
                tracksViewChanges={false}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

I don't know why `onPress` doesn't work on `PointMarker`. I pass it to react-native-maps `Marker`, but somehow it isn't triggered when I press on the markers.

I already tried searching for answers in react-native-maps official documentation on GitHub. In [this example](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/MarkerTypes.js) they do pretty much the same (call an arrow function onPress). However, it doesn't work in my case.

I'm testing the app on Android.

Comment: have you tried onSelect instead?

Comment: @EugenSunic, yes, unsuccessfully. Also, `onSelect` is iOS only, and I'm testing on Android.

Comment: onPress={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); alert(''something)}

Comment: Still doesn't work. Tried this way as well.

Comment: Also, in the example from the docs that I mentioned in the issue they don't use stopPropagation.

Comment: can you do a demo online for this?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It works correctly on Expo! Although what I pasted there is not the full code.

Comment: Got to test it on a real Android device, not an emulator - and it works. So I guess the problem's with the emulator itself.

Comment: so what solved the problem the `` onPress={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); alert(''something)} `` ?

Comment: @EugenSunic, I don't think so. On a real device as well as on Expo emulator everything works without `e.stopPropagation`.

Comment: yea make sense, the e.stoPropagation just stops the event bubbling but should not affect the onpress in any way...

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs you should set `stopPropagation` to true. Like this :

```
displayRouteLocations(locations) {
    return locations.map((location, i) => {
        return (
            <PointMarker
                key={i}
                coordinate={location}
                title={location.name}
                description={location.description}
                onPress={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); alert('test');}}
            />
        );
    });
}
```

For more information  : [`<Marker />` Component API](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md)

More information 2 : [Suggestion](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/758#issuecomment-284120321)

Comment: Thank you, but in the docs they say it's iOS only. I'm testing on Android. Will add this information to the issue description.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Also, in the example from the docs that I mentioned in the issue they don't use stopPropagation, and it works somehow.